# Wordpress buddypress: Missing argument error

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm getting an `missing argument` error here. Any Idea?

```
function my_approve( $user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta ) {
    // Send the email notification.
    wp_mail( $user_email, $user_login . ' Yay', 'you have been approved' );
}

add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'my_approve', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: have you update wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function hooked to `bp_core_activated_user` should accept 3 args only: `$user_id`, `$key` and `$user`. So your code should look like this:

```
function my_approve( $user_id, $key, $user ) {
    wp_mail( $user->user_email, $user->user_login . ' Yay', 'you have been approved' );
}
add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'my_approve', 10, 3 );
```